# How to convert datetime in python?

Tags: python, django

I am calling an user api from github here is my `views.py`:

```
def user(req, username):
    username = str.lower(username)
    with urlopen(f'https://api.github.com/users/{username}') as response:
        source = response.read()
    data = json.loads(source)
    context = {
        'username': username,
        'data': data,
    }
    return render(req, 'user.html', context)
```

and here is my template `index.html`:

```
<div class="profile text-center">
            <img src="{{data.avatar_url}}" class="border-primary" alt="profile-image">

            <h1>{{data.name}}</h1>
            <a href="">
                <p class="username text-primary">@{{data.login}}</p>
            </a>
            <p><i class="fal fa-map-marker-alt"></i> {{data.location}} <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                {{data.created_at}}
            </p>
       
</div>
```

[image]

How can i convert a string datetime from github api to look like "March 22, 2016"

Comment: there'e s strptime method in the datetime module.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
t1 = datetime.now()
t1.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Comment: can we convert it in templates file ?

Comment: {{ data.created_at|date:"M d, Y" }}

Comment: not showing anyhthing

Comment: This is how to format date in a django template.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/